# How retrieve all block transactions in the Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As you know there is chance to have multiple transaction in one block , depend on the batch size and orderer configuration.
I need to make only one call to return all transaction inside the block not one by one.

I could retrieve one transaction with queryTransaction by using fabric SDK.
like

```js
let response_payload = await channel.queryTransaction(trxnID, peer);
```

First Approach: implement a chanincode function and pass the block number which comes from eventHub along the method then inside the chaincode retrieve all transaction Ids and then make a query to find all transaction then stitch all together as result.

Second Approach:
retrieve the block inside with fabric sdk then parse all signed proposal in the payload of the block content.

Third Approach: 
retrieve the block inside with fabric sdk then retrieve the transaction ids or keys in the payload and then make a couch db query to retrieve all content .

Which approach do you think is more reasonable if not what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a your client set up correctly, there should be a

`LedgerClient` which has a function like

```
QueryBlock(blockNumber uint64, options ...ledger.RequestOption) (*common.Block, error)
```

Once you have the block, you can pull the data out of it

```
block, _ := QueryBlock(37)
data := block.GetData().GetData()
```

`data` is a `[][]byte`, and each entry is one transaction.

Comment: "If you have a your client set up correctly", can you please guide how to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the node client. I expect it to take a standard fabric-sdk config. Setting up a fabric-sdk config requires knowledge of the network, and is the set up I am referring to.